# Symfony2 ESI bug browser cache

Tags: symfony, browser, http-caching

I am using ESI caching at my web; there were working fine and today I cleared APC cache and sf2 cache and I see everything OK. But some people can't see the esi panels etc.

Why is this, and how to fix it? I don't understand why I and some friends can see it well and other people cannot?

```
Using symfony 2.1.7
```

Rendering this way:

```
$response=new Response();
$response= $this->render('HomePageBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(...
$response->setPrivate(true);
$response->setMaxAge(300);

return $response;
```

My web/app.php file

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';

$loader = new ApcClassLoader('tb_sf2', $loader);
$loader->register(true);

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();

// wrap the default AppKernel with the AppCache one
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

But if it would be an error I would not see the esi panels too, right?

I cleared the cache again some time (maybe 30mins later) one said:

> Now I can see the left menu, but the top, still nothing there

I cleared the log and than my friend made refresh... this log was added for each ESI panel:

```
[2013-05-27 23:03:17] request.INFO: Matched route "home_page_homepage" (parameters: "_controller": "TB\HomePageBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction", "_route": "home_page_homepage") [] []
[2013-05-27 23:03:17] app.INFO: Locale Query Guessing Service Loaded [] []
[2013-05-27 23:03:17] app.INFO: Locale has not been identified by the Query guessing service [] []
[2013-05-27 23:03:17] app.INFO: Locale Session Guessing Service Loaded [] []
[2013-05-27 23:03:17] app.INFO: Locale has been identified by guessing service: ( Session ) [] []
[2013-05-27 23:03:17] app.INFO: Setting [ en ] as defaultLocale for the Request [] []
[2013-05-27 23:03:17] security.DEBUG: Read SecurityContext from the session [] []
[2013-05-27 23:03:17] security.DEBUG: Reloading user from user provider. [] []
[2013-05-27 23:03:17] security.DEBUG: Username "MbrunoM" was reloaded from user provider. [] []
[2013-05-27 23:03:18] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
[2013-05-27 23:03:18] request.INFO: Matched route "notifications_box_esi" (parameters: "_controller": "TB\HomePageBundle\Controller\DefaultController::notificationsBoxEsiAction", "max": "10", "_route": "notifications_box_esi") [] []
[2013-05-27 23:03:18] app.INFO: Locale Query Guessing Service Loaded [] []
[2013-05-27 23:03:18] app.INFO: Locale has not been identified by the Query guessing service [] []

[2013-05-27 23:03:18] app.INFO: Locale Query Guessing Service Loaded [] []
[2013-05-27 23:03:18] app.INFO: Locale has not been identified by the Query guessing service [] []
[2013-05-27 23:03:18] app.INFO: Locale Session Guessing Service Loaded [] []
[2013-05-27 23:03:18] app.INFO: Locale has been identified by guessing service: ( Session ) [] []
[2013-05-27 23:03:18] app.INFO: Setting [ en ] as defaultLocale for the Request [] []
[2013-05-27 23:03:18] security.DEBUG: Read SecurityContext from the session [] []
[2013-05-27 23:03:18] security.DEBUG: Reloading user from user provider. [] []
[2013-05-27 23:03:18] security.DEBUG: Username "MbrunoM" was reloaded from user provider. [] []
[2013-05-27 23:03:18] security.DEBUG: Access is denied (and user is neither anonymous, nor remember-me) by "/var/www/domain.com/framework/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php" at line 70 [] []
[2013-05-27 23:03:18] security.DEBUG: Access is denied (and user is neither anonymous, nor remember-me) by "/var/www/domain.com/framework/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php" at line 70 [] []
```

Comment: provide more information , render methods, configuration .. which version of symfony? which reverse proxy ? varnish? internal? What do the logfiles say?

Comment: yea.. i over readed it in bunch of text and was hoping nobody notice before i edited it.. if you want please change your comment to from "t....." to "domain" :D

Comment: thx ;) now lets solve it :D

Comment: updated my answer with more information on the firewall configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your users are **allowed** to gain access to the ESI route by your **firewall**.

There might be an error in your Firewall configuration. Your user does not have access granted to route '*notifications_box_esi*'. The interesting line in your debug log is this one:

```
security.DEBUG: Access is denied (and user is neither anonymous, nor remember-me) by "/var/www/nonamepage/framework/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php" at line 70 [] [] [2013-05-27 23:03:18] security.
```

You firewall allows or restricts access to certain routes/urls based on roles or an access-decision-manager.

The configuration can be found in your security.yml:

```
security:

    # ...

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin/users, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

    # ... or with an access decision manager
    firewalls:
        your_firewall_name:
            pattern:    ^/
            # ...
```

You can check which roles a current user has with:

```
$this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getRoles();
```

Comment: yes i noticed but what to do with it? How to "grand" access to this route?

Comment: search the route. security checks might be implemented by is_granted() in twig aswell or in your controller action rendering the route. Possibly with JMSSecurityExtraBundle annotations ... don't know the structure of the project.

Comment: ow you have meaned this firewall sure i know them...aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa omg ... somebody punch me please... okay...the solution appeared inmediatly in my head after i saw:         - { path: ^/admin/users, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN } this lines... the image of two lines that i modified a week ago appeared in my head ... and i didnt clear cache from then that's why i coul not remember where the error could be... ah i had ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN for /esi/ and i am super admin that's why i saw everything good and my friend as well... ah ah

Comment: thx mate ;) give me some contact for you ? I will buy you a drink or send you some bucks? :)

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a problem from 2 years ago but I have got the same issue :
security.DEBUG: Access is denied (and user is neither anonymous, nor remember-me)

The problem is that if I do is granted in my LoginSuccessHandler which redirect to my page, I got the good role (ROLE_USER) but it still doesn't work.
I have already cleaned my cache, it doesn't make any difference.
If I go the symfony debug toolbar, it says : Authenticated? no (probably because the user has no roles)

Here is my security.yml and my LoginSuccessHandler :

```html
security:
  encoders:
    Mainbundle\Entity\Personne:
      algorithm:        sha512
      encode_as_base64: false
      iterations:       1

  role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_MANAGER, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

  providers:
    administrators:
      entity: { class: MainBundle:Personne }

  firewalls:
    #wsse_secured:
      #pattern:   ^/api/.*
      #stateless: true
      #wsse: true
    default:
      #pattern:      ^/
      pattern:      ^/wsse
      anonymous:    ~
      #wsse:         true
      form_login:
        post_only:           true
        use_forward:         false
        provider:            administrators
        csrf_provider:       form.csrf_provider
        csrf_parameter:      _csrf_token
        remember_me:         true
        login_path:          login_route
        check_path:          login_check
        default_target_path: admin
        failure_path:        null
        success_handler:     main.component.authentication.handler.login_success_handler
      logout:
        path:         logout
        target:       /
        success_handler: main.component.authentication.handler.logout_success_handler

  access_control:
    - { path: ^/wsse/admin, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/wsse, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    #- { path: ^/login_check, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    #providers:
        #webservice:
            #id: webservice_user_provider
        #in_memory:
            #memory: ~

    #encoders:
        #MainBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUser: sha512
```

```html
<?php
 
namespace MainBundle\Component\Authentication\Handler;
 
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use MainBundle\Entity\UserRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Mainbundle\Manager\UserManager;

class LoginSuccessHandler extends Controller implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{
 protected $router;
 protected $security;
 protected $usermanager;
 
 public function __construct($usermanager, Router $router, SecurityContext $security)
 {
  $this->router = $router;
  $this->security = $security;
  $this->usermanager = $usermanager;
 }
 
 public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
 {
  $personne = $token->getUser();
  $usermanager = $this->usermanager->getRepository();
  $role_array = $this->usermanager->findRole($personne->getId());
  $personne->setRoles($role_array);
  
  var_dump($this->security->getToken()->getUser()->getRoles());
  
  if ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'))
  {
   $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('category_index'));
  }
  elseif ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'))
  {
   $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('category_index'));
  } 
  elseif ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_USER'))
  {
   $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('admin'));
   // redirect the user to where they were before the login process begun.
   /*$referer_url = $request->headers->get('referer');
      
   $response = new RedirectResponse($referer_url);*/
  }
  elseif ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_MANAGER'))
  {
   $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('admin'));
  }
  return $response;
 } 
}
```